# Find file with longer of its name

Tags: linux, files, find

Please,

How can I find a file in folder that start with a character (for example 'A') and the longer of file name does not exceed 8 ?

I know to find a file I use `find fileName`, but how about the longer of file name ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the longer of file name"? Do you mean the remainder, as in everything after the `A`?

Comment: I have found that `find`'s options are so esoteric beyond just things like "`type`" that it is so much easier to just pipe it to `grep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard is what you need:

```
find . -path './A???????' -type d
```

WHERE:

> '.' *will search in the current directory.*
>
> -path './A???????' *this is a pattern: a word starting by 'A' and it has 8 characters total.*
>
> '-type d.' *will only show directories (not files).*